# regex make group appear only once

Tags: python, regex, text, french

I am trying to run a regex query on Python and I have the following problem:

In french, subjects of a sentence can appear before and after the verb.
For example, the sentence "she says" can be translated into "elle dit" and "dit-elle", where "elle" is "she" and "dit" is "says".

is it possible to capture only sentences containing "elle" and "dit", whether the subject "elle" is before or after the verb "dit" ? I have started with the following:

```
(elle).{0;10}(dit).{0;10}(elle)
```

But now I would like to make one of the `(elle)` optional when the other has been found. The `*` and `+` operators does not help in this case.

Comment: `(((elle).{0,10}(dit).{0,10}) | (.{0,10}(dit).{0,10}(elle)))` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a list of subjects and verbs in a list. Ultimately I would like to store the subjects and verbs found in a given sentence using (?P<subject>) and (?P<verb>), does your answer works with that ?

Comment: What does the `?P` stand for?

Comment: It indicates that this is a named capturing group, with the name being inside the < and > signs. See Wiktor's answer below for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PyPi `regex` module that can be installed using `pip install regex` (or `pip3 install regex`):

```
import regex
p = r'(?<=\b(?P<subject>il|elle)\b.{0,10})?\b(?P<predicate>dit|mange)\b(?=.{0,10}\b(?P<subject>il|elle)\b)?'
print( [x.groupdict() for x in regex.finditer(p, 'elle dit et dit-elle et il mange ... dit-il', regex.S)])
```

See the [online Python demo](https://tio.run/##dY5ND4IwDIbv/ore2BJcMF6B/QUTj@KBj4I1Y1vmSDDib8fxcfXUvunTp7Vv/zD6PM/UW@M8OOxwPFjIwEVMpllRMXlJX0P1xNrnpCZUCnlRiU8Sn5IvlxtgHTZUlx7zhvzUl7pbICaznfun4TI6WEfaM7iNonNmsMHjGYfWOBiB9PaRaEkHMzpmY4iWZQgR0C/luObQk4L1NAgh1gGpKN4FV37n8/wD)

The pattern may be created dynamically from variables:

```
subjects = ['il', 'elle']
predicates = ['dit', 'mange']
p = fr'(?<=\b(?P<subject>{"|".join(subjects)})\b.{0,10})?\b(?P<predicate>{"|".join(predicates)})\b(?=.{0,10}\b(?P<subject>{"|".join(subjects)})\b)?'
```

**Details**

- `(?<=\b(?P<subject>il|elle)\b.{0,10})?` - an optional look back to grab a whole word `il` or `elle` within 0 to 10 chars from
- `\b(?P<predicate>dit|mange)\b` - a whole word `dit` or `mange`
- `(?=.{0,10}\b(?P<subject>il|elle)\b)?` - an optional look forward to grab a whole word `il` or `elle` within 0 to 10 chars from the predicate.

Comment: Thank you, this is very good. I've given it a try using your pyhton demo link. Suppose the query only returns the verb (i.e the subject was different than 'il' or 'elle'), then it will return 'None' for the subject, and I have to avoid that. I figured out I could just delete every entry in the dictionnary that has 'None' for the subject, afterwards.